# CRON JOB run script daily at 6PM

Tags: automation, cron, cpanel, cron-task

so i set up my php page and the cronjob, in order to create an excel file with data in it, everyday at 6PM, but it is not working as intended.
it executes the script every 2 days not daily.
0 11 * * * wget -q --spider http://example.com/UserReport_Export.php

it had actually created the file at 1 june, and 3 june, while 2 june was not there. any idea?

i also put the time 11 in the script cuz of server time, in order to match 6PM in my local time, maybe it affects anything? thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can set the cron like this:

```
0 18 * * * wget -q --spider http://example.com/UserReport_Export.php
```

There are also online tools for cron jobs like [this](https://crontab.guru/#0_18_*_*_*) which can help out. The cron that you have set seems to be correct, if 11 is matching your local time.

> it had actually created the file at 1 june, and 3 june, while 2 june was not there. any idea?

Is it possible for the script or anything else to interfere with your excel file?

Comment: yes it matches my local times, and yes, i have started using a 3rd party service for cron job, on which i have input the same command and parameters and it works, guess its my hosts fault. thank you for input anyway. nothing interferes with my excel file, as if i made the cron to be executed every 1 minute, every 2 or every 5 minutes, it works, once a day wont work lol. but thank you for your input